# Responsive menu with resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to responsive button like this:
we have 15 buttons on a menu. When the browser is resizing, some buttons add to `<select>`
like this:
[image]

I have [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2dEr) to demonstrate the problem:

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: See this for a Demo: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ConvertMenuToDropdown/

Comment: Have you tried adding a `$(window).resize()` function?

Comment: You already have media selectors in your CSS. Why not use them to include/exclude certain buttons depending upon the window size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too much manipulation when the window is resized. I don't know if this can be done with CSS. You should prefer that..

But here is a working but dirty [**fiddle with Javascript/jQuery**](http://jsfiddle.net/CTAKR/).
You should listen to the `resize` event.

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {

    buildMenu();
    $(window).resize(function (event) {
        buildMenu();
    });

});
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete.when I select from <select> , url not open.I complete this: http://jsfiddle.net/CTAKR/2

Comment: I only wanted to show you the logic.. it's not a full application.

Comment: this code is very good but need to **jquery-1.9.1.js** with **263KB** !! how to edit your code **without jquery-1.9.1.js** ? thank you;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$(window).on('resize', function() { ... });` to detect ant change in width and act accordingly.

Here's a jQuery code that works

```
$(function() {

$("<select />").appendTo($("nav"));

var $select = $('nav select');
$select.hide();

$("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
    "value"   : "",
    "text"    : "Go to..."
}).appendTo($select);

$("nav a").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
        "value"   : el.attr("href"),
        "text"    : el.text()
    }).appendTo($select);
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    console.log($(window).width());
    if($(window).width() < 960) {
        $($select).show();
        $('nav ul').hide();
    }
    else if($(window).width() > 960) {
        $($select).hide();
        $('nav ul').show();
    }
});    

$select.change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
});
```

[**Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/N2dEr/1/). See demo here: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N2dEr/1/show)

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way around, it's more flexible, so, the default situation is a dropdown menu.

In javascript listen to the window resize event, on resize, measure width available, start putting options from the dropdown in the menu till it's wider than the screen, remove last item, done.

Answer (score 1):

You could give each button and duplicated option a class, and then use media queries to show and hide the ones that you wish to display, keeping the logic in the JS to a minimum:

```
@media (max-width: SIZE-1) {
    li.about-us,
    li.support-1,
    li.support-2,
    li.support-3,
    li.etc {
        display: none;
    }

    option.about-us,
    option.support-1,
    option.support-2,
    option.support-3,
    option.etc {
        display: none;
    }
}
```