# CSS : Collapsing navigation, one element at a time

Tags: javascript, css

Collapsing navigation, like the one you get from Twitter Bootstrap, is a "all or nothing" approach which either shows all or hides all navigational elements.

However, is there a way to hide navigation elements incrementally, one by one, as the space gets smaller and smaller? That is:

```
640px:
Link 1 | Link 2 | Link 3 | Link 4 | Link 5

600px:
Link 1 | Link 2 | Link 3 | Link 4 | More

560px:
Link 1 | Link 2 | Link 3 | More
```

I could always hard-code the pixel values, but it would be great to have a solution where I do not have to take care of adjusting the pixel values if, say, I add a link element or change the text of one.

Comment: Why would I not do it? If you are on a desktop, and you resize your screen which gives the webpage 25px less to show - you'd end up having all navigation links hidden in a single dropdown. I'd like only the one or two rightmost elements in this case to be hidden in a "show more" dropdown.

Comment: See Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842076/responsive-menu-with-resizing/16842417#16842417

The accepted answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i write an example for what do you'de to do :

i think you have your html code like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/resize.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#" id="link1">link1</a> <span id="2">|</span> <a href="#" id="link2">link2</a> <span id="3">|</span> <a href="#" id="link3">link3</a> <span id="4">|</span> <a href="#" id="link4">link4</a> <span id="5">|</span> <a href="#" id="link5">link5</a> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

sach as you can see , i add a javascript tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/resize.js"></script> in the head of the page`, this file look like this :

```
// resize.js

$(document).ready(function(){
  // add a (more) link with javascript to ensure that it exist only if javascript is enabled
  $("#navigation").append('<a href="#" id="more">more</a>'); // #navigation is a div container of our links

  // in the load of document , you check the width of the browser and apply hide or show links switch what do you need
  var width_of_window = $(window).width();

  if (width_of_window <= 560) {
    $("#link5, #link4, #5, #4").hide(); 
  }

  if(width_of_window > 560 && width_of_window <= 600){
    $("#link4").show(); $("#link5").hide(); 
  }

  if(width_of_window >= 640){
    $("#more").hide();
  }


  // here resize function is handled when you resize the navigator 
  $(window).resize(function() {
    width_of_window = $(window).width(); // get the width of the window each time you resize it

  //apply what do you need

    if (width_of_window <= 560) {
        $("#link5, #link4, #5, #4").hide(); // #link5 and link4 are the id of links and #5, #4 are separator '|' between links (i added | separator between span, see html code)
        if( $("#more").is(':hidden') ){
            $("#more").show();
        }
     }

     if(width_of_window > 560 && width_of_window <= 600){

        $("#link4").show(); $("#link5").hide(); 
        if( $("#more").is(':hidden') ){
            $("#more").show();
        }
     }


     if(width_of_window >= 640){
        $("#more").hide();
        $("#link4, #link5").show();
     }
  });


});
```

for more details about resize function you can see documentation here [.resize() | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

i hope that can help you, if you have any question about code , write a comment ^^

Comment: I'd advise against a JS approach. It can be achieved with media queries (so pure CSS) only. Then again, maybe the client's browser doesn't support media queries.

Comment: media queries can also be a good solution , but we don't know about what he prefer, i think if he want to do this for navigation only, it become a good idea to do this with js, and switch his tag , he want js and css ! finally we are suggest a differents ways to him and he can take the best :D

Comment: Thanks; I went for the JS approach. Media queries can probably do it do; but JS was faster to implement and I'm on a really tight schedule...so it's the solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

Check media queries they might help to have this behaviour [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: There are various examples available for media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries