# what css framework is this website using?

Tags: css, frameworks

I'm creating a web app and I want people to be able to use it from their phones
this website seems to be using a great responsive css framework:

http://seenive.com/

when you zoom in a lot the top menu collapses very nicely.

any one knows what framework they are using?

Comment: the source code seems auto generated <link href="/Content/css/styles?v=5IfHqK7pkNDzgt9jdAmxoBWRBpRHYcs0J5MJBWceMs41" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: you can try using https://www.similartech.com/ to know techs about websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gumby Framework](http://gumbyframework.com/docs/grid/#!/)
I never use this framework but they are used that

Github: https://github.com/GumbyFramework/Gumby

Answer (score 1):

The menu collapses not because of zoom but `window.innerWidth`. When it decreases below a certain width, the menu collapses into drop-down menu.

You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842076/responsive-menu-with-resizing/16842417#16842417) | [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N2dEr/1/show/)

Edit: Many frameworks provide this effect but you really don't need one if you only want this effect